# DNS without www is not working

Tags: dns

I've got a domain name that is perfectely reachable using http://www.example.com

I would like that this same domain would be reachable using http://example.com

Unfortunately, with my actual DNS config, it doesn't work.
Here what I have in DNS configuration :

```
*   CNAME   www
www CNAME   address_my_domain.
```

I was thinking that the wildcard would redirect to www, but it seems that I'm wrong... What can I define in my DNS to have the site accessible without www ?
Thanks for help

Comment: If you have only that in your configuration, you have nowhere the IP addresses of your website(s) as that would need `A` or `AAAA` records. On the contrary if the target of your CNAME for `www` is really an IP address, then it is wrong as the data of a CNAME should be an hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you actually don't need either of those records, the https:// and www. are not relevant, you can just make the root of your zone point to the ip of your site via an `A` record:

```
@ IN A ip-address
```

Where in place of `@` you can put the full address of your zone, e.g. `example.com.`, but usually the `@` symbol is recognized as the zone root. If your site is actually hosted using another domain then that's tricky, because your zone root cannot be the name of a `CNAME`, e.g. you can't have

```
@ IN CNAME site.address
```

You would have to have something like

```
portal.example.com IN CNAME site.address
```

Adding some more details:

The reason your site is resolving at www.example.com is because you added a record named `www` on you zone `example.com`, and www.example.com is the record that has the CNAME to your site, but example.com is the root of your zone and is a record in itself, it does not have a CNAME to your site so that's why it's not going there, the http:// is irrelevant to the DNS records, your zone apex record, `@` or `example.com` cannot itself be a CNAME, so your possible solutions are designating a record to be the CNAME for the site, e.g. `portal IN CNAME site.address`, where people would use portal.example.com to access your site, or depending on the DNS software you're using, you can make an alias record that allows for an apex record to be a CNAME but through other fancy means, Amazon's Route 53 allows for this

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. So this means, that adding the following line : @ 300 IN A ip_adddress_to_my_site will not help to solve the problem ?...

Comment: that should solve your problem, the CNAME issue is only if you have to point another non-ip FQDN, but if you are hosting on a list of ips then you could make an `A` record with the list of your ips and have the name be the apex like that

Comment: Ok, i'll try and let you know. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3):

You can use wildcards to add subdomains, but not to subtract them - e.g.:

```
*.example.com.   IN CNAME example.com.
```

You'll need an A record to point to the correct ip address for the 'base' domain:

```
example.com.   IN  A   1.2.3.4
```

Comment: The domain I've got has many subdomains that are located on different servers, like this :

@           10800 IN A 1.2.3.4
subdomain_1 300   IN A 1.2.3.4
subdomain_2 300   IN A 10.20.30.40
subdomain_3 300   IN A 10.20.30.40
....many other subdomains...
*           10800 IN CNAME www
www         10800 IN CNAME gpaas14.dc0.gandi.net.
So, if I have to add this line :

*.example.com.   IN CNAME example.com.
all subdomains are going to be redirected on example.com., no ?...

Comment: The `wildcard` is for all `not-configured subdomains`, since the subdomains you mentioned have their own records the `wildcard` will not work for them, only for all other "non-existing" subdomains.

Comment: Do not use wildcards until you master DNS and applications configuration. Otherwise you will hit a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I was using  AWS Amplify with GoDaddy and I configured my DNS records with these two entries to get it working.

```
Type  Name  Data
CNAME *     dk************nes.cloudfront.net.
CNAME www   dkihdeom86nes.cloudfront.net.
```

Initially I only had the www entry which is why it wasn't working for me.

To test it make sure you open an incognito or private browser window to remove caching.

Comment: Are the two Data items you have listed, two different DNS targets provided by cloudfront? Im trying to get this to work with Squarespace domain registrar and my heroku app - and am wondering how to do it as the information is limited (and in my experience Squarespace is a terrible domain registrar.)